# MySQLDialect working for PostgreSQL database

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, postgresql

In my Spring MVC app, I am using PostgreSQL DB 9.3 and Hibernate as JPA vendor. Below is my application-dao.xml file:

```
<bean id="propDataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mysql" />
    <property name="username" value="abcd" />
    <property name="password" value="abcd" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="emf"/>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean id="emf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="propDataSource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.trua.prol"/>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">3</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size">50</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">10</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I used MySQLDialect by mistake for providing hibernate.dialect and found it to be working, surprisingly. When I used the right dialect PostgreSQLDialect, it also worked.

Is this intended? Can I use MySQL dialect with Postgre DBs as well?

Comment: SQL is SQL. As long as you don't use any specific database features each dialect *might* work. As soon as you start to use functions or specific databse options, things start to break apart.

Comment: MySQL uses some non-standard stuff like e.g. `+` for String concatenation or `\`` for quoting objects which Postgres will refuse. If your queries don't make use of such non-standard syntax, then you won't notice the difference.